# Does SQLite datetime() accept fractional modifier values?

Tags: sqlite

As the title states, does the SQLite datetime() function accept fractional (REAL/float/etc) values for its modifier clauses? The [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) doesn't seem to state explicitly one way or another on integer vs real. The fact that it lists `NNN` for minutes, hours, days, months, and years, but `NNN.NNNN` for seconds suggests that only seconds would take a fractional value. However, simple testing seems to show that fractional values are acceptable to any of these modifiers.

```
CREATE TABLE a (rel TEXT);
INSERT INTO a VALUES('0.25 days');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('0.5 days');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('1 days');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('1.5 days');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('2 days');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('7 days');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('14 days');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('0.25 months');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('0.5 months');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('1 months');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('1.5 months');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('6 months');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('0.5 years');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('1 years');
INSERT INTO a VALUES('1.5 years');

SELECT rel, datetime('now', 'localtime', rel) FROM a;

rel         datetime('now', 'localtime', rel)
----------  ---------------------------------
0.25 days   2020-03-10 05:21:35              
0.5 days    2020-03-10 11:21:35              
1 days      2020-03-10 23:21:35              
1.5 days    2020-03-11 11:21:35              
2 days      2020-03-11 23:21:35              
7 days      2020-03-16 23:21:35              
14 days     2020-03-23 23:21:35              
0.25 month  2020-03-17 11:21:35              
0.5 months  2020-03-24 23:21:35              
1 months    2020-04-09 23:21:35              
1.5 months  2020-04-24 23:21:35              
6 months    2020-09-09 23:21:35              
0.5 years   2020-09-08 11:21:35              
1 years     2021-03-09 23:21:35              
1.5 years   2021-09-08 11:21:35
```

I'm mostly just wondering if anyone has <s>a conclusive answer</s> some other proof or experience if this behavior--correct datetime calculation from fractional modifiers--can be relied upon, or if it's simply a quirk.

Comment: Anything except the official documentation is **not** conclusive, by definition. SQLite doesn't even have a date type. Why aren't you storing the *actual* dates anyway? Are you trying to store intervals or offsets instead of dates? If so, `0.25 months` is ambiguous - are we talking about 28,29,30 or 31 days?. `datetime` allows you to specify an exact value by using multiple modifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a quirk.  As uncomfortable as one should be when relying on behavior that appears to be outside a limited inference from the docs, it may be time to update the docs.

SQLite's `datetime` implementation in  [`src/date.c`](https://sqlite.org/src/artifact/6c408fdd2e9ddf6e) understands NNN to mean fractional numbers:

```
/*
** The following table defines various date transformations of the form
**
**            'NNN days'
**
** Where NNN is an arbitrary floating-point number and "days" can be one
** of several units of time.
*/
```

Moreover, the test cases in [`test/date.test`](https://sqlite.org/src/artifact/9b73bbeb1b82d9c1) do cover some fractional datetime arithmetic in units larger than seconds:

```
$ perl -lnE 'say if /\d\.\d+\s+(days|hours|minutes|months|years)/' date.test 
datetest 2.24 {datetime('2003-10-22 12:34','1.5 months')} {2003-12-07 12:34:00}
datetest 2.26 {datetime('2003-10-22 12:34','+10.5 minutes')} \
datetest 2.27 {datetime('2003-10-22 12:34','-1.25 hours')} \
datetest 8.15 {datetime('now','1.5 months')} {2003-12-07 12:34:00}
datetest 8.17 {datetime('now','+10.5 minutes')} {2003-10-22 12:44:30}
datetest 8.18 {datetime('now','-1.25 hours')} {2003-10-22 11:19:00}
datetest 13.21 {julianday(2454832.5,'-1.5 months')} {2454786.5}
datetest 13.22 {julianday(2454832.5,'+1.5 months')} {2454878.5}
datetest 13.23 {julianday(2454832.5,'-1.5 years')} {2454284.0}
datetest 13.24 {julianday(2454832.5,'+1.5 years')} {2455380.0}
datetest 13.30 {date('2000-01-01','+1.5 years')} {2001-07-02}
datetest 13.31 {date('2001-01-01','+1.5 years')} {2002-07-02}
datetest 13.32 {date('2002-01-01','+1.5 years')} {2003-07-02}
datetest 13.33 {date('2002-01-01','-1.5 years')} {2000-07-02}
datetest 13.34 {date('2001-01-01','-1.5 years')} {1999-07-02}
```

As a caveat, note that for this kind of datetime arithmetic, SQLite uses normalized time intervals that don't always match our civil reckoning:  60 second minutes (but leap seconds!), 24 hour days (but daylight savings adjustments!), 30 day months (hello, Sept, Apr, Jun, and Nov — where are your friends?), and 365 day years (but leap years!).